# Realistic simulated elevation data in R / Perlin noise

Tags: r, perlin-noise

Does anyone know how to create a simulation raster elevation dataset - i.e. a 2d matrix of realistic elevation values - in R?  R's `jitter` doesn't seem appropriate.  In Java/Processing the `noise()` function achieves this with a [Perlin noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) algorithm e.g.:

```
size(200, 200);
float ns = 0.03; // for scaling
for (float i=0; i<200; i++) {
  for (float j=0; j<200; j++) {
    stroke(noise(i*ns, j*ns) * 255);
    point(i, j);
  }
}
```

[image]

But I've found no references to Perlin noise in R literature.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: see either the `RandomFields` package (methods for simulating a wide variety of Gaussian random fields), or perhaps a fractal surface: http://www.oceanographerschoice.com/2010/10/fractal-landscapes-in-r-part-two/ (I have some old code for this)

Comment: A quick search [brings up some C++ code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/66480-perlin-noise/), which should not be too difficult to adjust. You could use `Rcpp` to use it directly or translate it to R.

Comment: Thanks Ben, Roland. The oceanograherschoice blog like a useful thing to try at some point when I have time, as would be learning C++.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an implementation in R,
following the explanations in
http://webstaff.itn.liu.se/~stegu/TNM022-2005/perlinnoiselinks/perlin-noise-math-faq.html

```
perlin_noise <- function( 
  n = 5,   m = 7,    # Size of the grid for the vector field
  N = 100, M = 100   # Dimension of the image
) {
  # For each point on this n*m grid, choose a unit 1 vector
  vector_field <- apply(
    array( rnorm( 2 * n * m ), dim = c(2,n,m) ),
    2:3,
    function(u) u / sqrt(sum(u^2))
  )
  f <- function(x,y) {
    # Find the grid cell in which the point (x,y) is
    i <- floor(x)
    j <- floor(y)
    stopifnot( i >= 1 || j >= 1 || i < n || j < m )
    # The 4 vectors, from the vector field, at the vertices of the square
    v1 <- vector_field[,i,j]
    v2 <- vector_field[,i+1,j]
    v3 <- vector_field[,i,j+1]
    v4 <- vector_field[,i+1,j+1]
    # Vectors from the point to the vertices
    u1 <- c(x,y) - c(i,j)
    u2 <- c(x,y) - c(i+1,j)
    u3 <- c(x,y) - c(i,j+1)
    u4 <- c(x,y) - c(i+1,j+1)
    # Scalar products
    a1 <- sum( v1 * u1 )
    a2 <- sum( v2 * u2 )
    a3 <- sum( v3 * u3 )
    a4 <- sum( v4 * u4 )
    # Weighted average of the scalar products
    s <- function(p) 3 * p^2 - 2 * p^3
    p <- s( x - i )
    q <- s( y - j )
    b1 <- (1-p)*a1 + p*a2
    b2 <- (1-p)*a3 + p*a4
    (1-q) * b1 + q * b2
  }
  xs <- seq(from = 1, to = n, length = N+1)[-(N+1)]
  ys <- seq(from = 1, to = m, length = M+1)[-(M+1)]
  outer( xs, ys, Vectorize(f) )
}

image( perlin_noise() )
```

[image: Perlin noise]

You can have a more fractal structure by adding those matrices,
with different grid sizes.

```
a <- .6
k <- 8
m <- perlin_noise(2,2,2^k,2^k)
for( i in 2:k )
  m <- m + a^i * perlin_noise(2^i,2^i,2^k,2^k)
image(m)
m[] <- rank(m) # Histogram equalization
image(m)
```

[image: Perlin noise, Sum with different grid sizes]

Comment: Spot on Vincent :) I've spent a couple of hours wading through other implementations - this code is far more elegant than mine would've turned out!  Do you know who deserves attribution if necessary?

Comment: Thanks also for the edit. I'm intrigued by the repeating blips where _high_ and _low_ extreme points neighbour each other. The model seems perfect aside from these points.

Comment: That artefact was due to a missing `sqrt` when normalizing the vectors; I have fixed it and updated the plots accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method:

```
require(geoR)
sim <- grf(441, grid="reg", cov.pars=c(1, .25))
image(sim, col=gray(seq(1, .1, l=30)))
```

[image]

Can extract object data with `cbind(sim[[1]], z = sim[[2]])`

Comment: nice and simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Also now some functions in the {ambient} package.